# Selecting the most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have data structured like this:

```
ID | Enrolment_Date | Appointment1_Date | Appointment2_Date | .... | Appointment150_Date |
112  01/01/2015       01/02/2015          01/03/2018                 01/08/2018    
113  01/06/2018       01/07/2018          NULL                       NULL
114  01/04/2018       01/05/2018          01/06/2018                 NULL
```

I need a new variable which counts the number of months between the enrolment_date and the most recent appointment. The challenge is is that all individuals have a different number of appointments.

Update: I agree with the comments that this is poor table design and it needs to be reformatted. Could proposed solutions please include suggested code on how to transform the table?

Comment: I seriously feel that your table structure is wrong. You should have new row for each appointment rather than column

Comment: Create two separate tables - one called users and one called appointments. The users table contains the user id, enrollment date and any other specific user information. Each row in the appointments table contains the user's unique id and a specific appointment date. Structuring your tables like this will make it easier to write a query to get days/months since last appointment.

Comment: @codeLover I agree - Was an output i've been provided. I'm not sure how to switch it around though. Any suggested code?

Comment: I completely agree with the suggestion provided by @Sean Cox. Please restructure your table and then discussion can be taken up further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the OP is currently stuck with this bad design, I will point out a temporary solution. As others have suggested, you really must change the structure here. For now, this will suffice:

```
SELECT '['+ NAME + '],' FROM sys.columns WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID ('TableA') -- find all columns, last one probably max appointment date

SELECT ID, 
      Enrolment_Date, 
      CASE WHEN Appointment150_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment150_Date)
           WHEN Appointment149_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment149_Date)
           WHEN Appointment148_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment148_Date)
           WHEN Appointment147_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment147_Date)
           WHEN Appointment146_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment146_Date)
           WHEN Appointment145_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment145_Date)
           WHEN Appointment144_Date IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF (MONTH, Enrolment_Date, Appointment144_Date) -- and so on
      END AS NumberOfMonths
 FROM TableA
```

This is a very ugly temporary solution and should be considered as such.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to restructure your data, the given structure is poor database design. 
Create two separate tables - one called users and one called appointments. The users table contains the user id, enrollment date and any other specific user information. Each row in the appointments table contains the user's unique id and a specific appointment date. Structuring your tables like this will make it easier to write a query to get days/months since last appointment. 
For example:

```
Users Table: 

ID, Enrollment_Date
1, 2018-01-01 
2, 2018-03-02
3, 2018-05-02

Appointments Table: 

ID, Appointment_Date
1, 2018-01-02
1, 2018-02-02
1, 2018-02-10
2, 2018-05-01
```

You would then be able to write a query to join the two tables together and calculate the difference between the enrollment date and min value of the appointment date.

Answer (score 0):

It is better if you can create two tables.

**Enrolment Table (dbo.Enrolments)**

```
ID   |   EnrolmentDate

1    | 2018-08-30

2    | 2018-08-31
```

**Appointments Table (dbo.Appointments)**

```
ID | EnrolmentID | AppointmentDate
1  | 1           | 2018-09-02
2  | 1           | 2018-09-03 
3  | 2           | 2018-09-01
4  | 2           | 2018-09-03
```

Then you can try something like this.

If you want the count of months from Enrolment Date to the final appointment date then use below query.

```
SELECT E.ID, E.EnrolmentDate, A.NoOfMonths
FROM dbo.Enrolments E
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, E.EnrolmentDate, MAX(A.AppointmentDate)) AS NoOfMonths
  FROM dbo.Appointments A
  WHERE A.EnrolmentId = E.ID
) A
```

And, If you want the count of months from Enrolment Date to the nearest appointment date then use below query.

```
SELECT E.ID, E.EnrolmentDate, A.NoOfMonths
FROM dbo.Enrolments E
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT DATEDIFF(mm, E.EnrolmentDate, MIN(A.AppointmentDate)) AS NoOfMonths
  FROM dbo.Appointments A
  WHERE A.EnrolmentId = E.ID
) A
```

Try this on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3f8b/3)

Answer (score 0):

You have a lousy data structure, as others have noted.  You really one a table with one row per appointment.  After all, what happens after the 150th appointment?

```
select t.id, t.Enrolment_Date,
       datediff(month, t.Enrolment_Date, m.max_Appointment_Date) as months_diff
from t cross apply
     (select max(Appointment_Date) as max_Appointment_Date
      from (values (Appointment1_Date),
                   (Appointment2_Date),
                   . . .
                   (Appointment150_Date)
           ) v(Appointment_Date)
     ) m;
```